# Create string in CELL B1 from multiple rows in ColumnA

Tags: sql, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a column in a worksheet:

```
ColumnA
wer
rfvg
swe
dfe
```

I would like to create a string `'wer','rfvg','swe','dfe'`  for use in a TSQL query

```
SELECT value
FROM table 
WHERE code IN ('wer','rfvg','swe','dfe')
```

What I do now:

```
1. put CONCATENATE("'";A1;"',") in B1
2. drag it all the way down
3. copy+ paste the generated values in ColumnB into my query
```

What I get is this:

```
SELECT value
FROM table 
WHERE code IN ('wer',
'rfvg',
'swe',
'dfe')
```

Since these last can contain up to 100 codes that is really annoying.
I would like to create a single continuous string in cell B1.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanx for thinking with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a macro to do this:

```
Sub BuildListForQuery
    Dim oCells As Object, aCell As Object, oDoc As Object
    Dim iColumnA As Integer, sList As String
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    iColumnA = 0
    oColumn = oDoc.Sheets(0).Columns(iColumnA)
    oRanges = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCellRanges")
    oRanges.insertByName("", oColumn)
    oCells = oRanges.Cells.createEnumeration
    If Not oCells.hasMoreElements Then Print "Sorry, no text to display"
    While oCells.hasMoreElements
        aCell = oCells.nextElement
        If sList = "" Then
            sList = "'" + aCell.String + "'"
        Else
            sList = sList + ",'" + aCell.String + "'"
        End If
    Wend
    aCell = oDoc.Sheets(0).getCellRangeByName("B1")
    aCell.setString(sList)
End Sub
```

Result in B1 is `'wer','rfvg','swe','dfe'`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

- Put in C1 `=CONCATENATE("'",A1,"'")`
- Put in D1 `=CONCATENATE(B1,",'",INDIRECT("A" & COLUMN()-2),"'")`

  - `COLUMN` returns a number for the column: A is 1, B is 2, etc.
  - `INDIRECT` takes a string entry and returns the contents of a cell address, in this case the contents of the cell in column A, row [calculated from column number].  So column D (4) looks at row 2 (4 - 2), column E (5) looks at row 3 (5 - 2), etc.
- Copy and paste D1 over however many columns you want (100 columns would be to column CX)
- Put in some other cell, we'll say B3 for purposes of this post, `=COUNTA(A1:A100)` to show how many entries you have in column A
- In B1 (the cell where you want the final string) put the formula `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,B3+2))` - of course replace `B3` with wherever you actually put the `COUNTA` formula

  - `ADDRESS` takes (row number, column number) - here [row 1, column (however many entries in column A + 2)] and returns a LetterNumber cell address

Comment: The number of columns can be diferent each time, that reduces the effectiveness of this solution greatly. I did learn from this solution though! Thanx!